# Android intents from the standard browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, standards

Is it possible to transmit text from the standard browser to my own app ? Are there maybe any broadcast intents that i can listen to when selecting text in the browser?

the only thing i know is, that there's an intent triggered when sharing a page, but that's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to transmit text from the standard browser to my own app ?

I have no idea what "transmit text" means.

You can set up a link that will launch one of your application's activities, if the activity advertises itself properly in the manifest. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler) that demonstrates this. The key is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.commonsware.android.urlhandler" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>
        <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/cw">
                <activity android:name="URLHandler" android:label="@string/app_name">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                         <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="com.commonsware.android.MY_ACTION"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                        </intent-filter>
             </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

For example, the third `<intent-filter>` will be triggered by a link to [this non-existent site](http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com).

> Are there maybe any broadcast intents that i can listen to when selecting text in the browser?

No, because that would be a privacy violation.

Comment: transmit is ment like setting data to an intent, e.g. an selected text. ok think clipboard of the browser is probably private too.